# failed to start jboss service with non root user

Tags: linux, jboss, centos, jboss6.x

I tried to start jobs service with non root user and group but I received `runuser cannot set groups operation not permitted jobs` error in /var/log/jboss-as/console.log. I installed and configured jboss service with non root user. It worked fine with root, but failed to start/stop/restart jboss service with non root user. I have no ideas why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

give permissions to the folder like

chmod 775 -R